# Eclipse HTML validation ignoring BASE tag

Tags: html, eclipse

I am using Eclipse to edit a static web project.  The web content folder has sub-folders containing HTML files, with all of them sharing common resources like images.  I want to use the BASE tag in the HTML files, so that they can use URLs relative to the web content folder, rather than each of their sub folders.

[image: Project Structure in Eclipse]

subdir/myfile.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <base href="..">
 </head>
 <body>
  <img src="images/bluebox.gif">
 </body>
</html>
```

This works fine in a web browser.  However, when I open subdir/myfile.html in Eclipse, the img tag is underlined in red and on mouseover shows the error message "Undefined Image file ("images/bluebox.gif")."

[image]

How can I configure Eclipse to recognize the BASE tag when locating referenced resources?

The version of Eclipse I am using is Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)

Comment: The HTML Validator that corresponds to the editor shown makes no attempt to validate this. Do you have something else installed that's doing it?

Comment: I tried going to Window -> Preferences -> Validation and disabling all validators, yet the line is still flagged as an error.  Strangely, if I check the box for "Suspend all Validators", the line is NOT flagged as an error.  The validator responsible must not be one of those visible in that list.